# Redirect in subfolder .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have file **/abc/index.html**

I want to access it via **/index.html** with some rules in **/abc/.htaccess** file.

Is this possible? How?!

Comment: Is it really necessary to have the .htaccess in /abc/? It'd be a lot easier to have it one directory higher.

Comment: Thank you for quick answers guys, you made me think. Sorry for my english — i can read and understand, but never try to write before. Hope you can understand me too. I have very big monstrous site that move full to subfolder. Site have links to js, css, img like this: /build/js/some.js I'm lazy to replace all of them and check it after. Also i have no access to parent dir. I try to read Apache manual and think it is impossible to redirect from .htaccess in subfolder. Now i try to find another way.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, i try to apply it now

Comment: @Art: I deleted my answer since .htaccess in `/abc/` will not be invoked if original URL doesn't have `/abc/` in it.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I think it's not going to be possible with a htaccess in the /abc/ folder. You'll have to find another approach, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess should not be in /abc/, bit in the root /.

In that case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/
RewriteRule index.html abc/index.html [L]
```